# Disposing objects to clear memory

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static void GetAllProductsFromIndexes_AndPutInDB(List<IndexModel> indexes)
{
    BlockingCollection<IndexModel> inputQueue = CreateInputQueue(indexes);
    BlockingCollection<Product> productsQueue = new BlockingCollection<Product>(5000);

    var producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (IndexModel index in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                byte[] unconvertedByteArray;
                string xml;
                string url = @"https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/en/";

                unconvertedByteArray = DownloadIcecatFile(index.IndexNumber.ToString() + ".xml", url);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unconvertedByteArray);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                GetProductDetails(product, xmlDoc, index);

                XmlNodeList nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature"));
                product.FeaturesLink = GetProductFeatures(product, nodeList);

                nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductGallery/ProductPicture"));
                product.Images = GetProductImages(nodeList);
                productsQueue.Add(product);
            }

        })).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var context = new ProductContext())
            {
                var batch = new List<Product>();
                foreach (Product readyProduct in productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    AddProductToBatch(readyProduct, context, batch);
                    if (batch.Count >= 100)
                    {
                        context.Products.AddRange(batch);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        foreach (var p in batch)
                        {
                            context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
                        }
                        batch.Clear();
                    }
                }
                context.Products.AddRange(batch);
                context.SaveChanges();
                foreach (var p in batch)
                {
                    context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }
            }

        });
    }
    Task.WaitAll(producers);
    productsQueue.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Im trying to get 114000 products into the database with a producer consumer pattern.
So far I have managed to get around 40000 products into the database in around 1.5 hours.
But then the program stops because I run out of memory. 
Im obviously not disposing something right, after I have finished using it, I just can't figure out how to dispose of f.x. the index from the inputQueue once the product has been added to the productsQueue.

Comment: You know you can use `Parallel.ForEach(...)` rather than having one loop that creates tasks and then another loop that runs them?

Comment: Yes I know, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Also the producers produce Products then places them in the queue,
The consumers each make a batch of 100 products from the queue and places them in the database. It's 2 different tasks, which is why I'm using 2 loops that run at the same time.

Comment: I see. I am assuming that each `product` is quite a large object, since it includes all of the features coming from the XML + an image. Would it make sense to use a concurrent queue type for your `productsQueue` to be able to dequeue objects when processing them? Otherwise I fear that 114000 * your object size ends up being too big.

Comment: Yes thats exactly my problem. Do you have any code examples how I can do this? Right now i have set the limit on my productsQueue to 5000, and I hoped this would be enough to make sure the memory never run out, but it seems something is still not being being cleared in the memory correctly.

Comment: Actually, your call to `productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` should ensure that products are removed from the `productsQueue`. Your producers are producing faster than what your consumers can consume, which is why your `productsQueue` builds up, and I assume that 5000 items in the `productsQueue` is still too much. You could decrease the queue size to less than 5000 and at the same time increase your consumers to be more than 10.

Comment: That said, I still think that queueing the entire `product` object is not the best way to go for large objects like that. Could you queue something smaller and inflate in the consumer? Perhaps just add the image in the consumer? Also, out of curiosity, is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?